# How to match multiple substrings in jQuery combobox autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I found more than a couple examples of this with a plain jquery autocomplete but not in a way that will work with the autocomplete included in the combobox code from [the demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) because the structure of the code is structured so differently.

I want to match every item that has all of the search tokens anywhere in any word. I don't need to match the start of any word, any part of it is fine. I don't care if the search strings are highlighted in the autocomplete list if that makes things too complicated.

Desired search/result combos: (please excuse the spacing)
"**fi th**"  "**fi** rst second **th** ird"
"**rs on**"  "fi **rs** t sec **on** d third"
"**ec rd**"  "first s **ec** ond thi **rd**"
but not limited to any max/min length or number of tokens.

### EDIT

I figured part of it out using the code structure from the other autocorrect I had working.

```
source: function( requestObj, responseFunc ) {
    var matchArry = $("select > option").map(function(){return this.innerHTML;}).get();
    var srchTerms   = $.trim(requestObj.term).split(/\s+/);

    // For each search term, remove non-matches
    $.each (srchTerms, function (J, term) {
        var regX = new RegExp (term, "i");
        matchArry = $.map (matchArry, function (item) {
            if( regX.test(item) ){
                return{
                    label: item,
                    value: item,
                    option: HTMLOptionElement
                } ? item :null;
            }
        } );
    });

    // Return the match results
    responseFunc (matchArry);
},
```

and

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
    $("destination").val(ui.item.value);    // I added this line
},
```

but I can't get both multiple words AND being able to click to select working at the same time.

If I remove the `} ? item :null;` on the return in the map function I can click to select an item. If I leave it I can type multiple words, but I can't click any of the items...

Is that the problem or the `option: this`? I've tried replacing it with `HTMLOptionElement` and `null` and I'm stuck.

I am able to set the value of another field with `ui.item.value` within the select label but that doesn't put the value in the search box or close the dropdown menu.

Comment: In your code, are you using the same type of source as the example? An underlying select list? Or are you getting the autocomplete data from the server?

Comment: So far it's exactly as the jQuery-ui demo

Comment: Solved it myself, see below.  I really hope someone else can make use of this someday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a whim I added `ui.item.option = ui.item.value;` to the select label and everything works as expected. the option: value in source doesn't seem to matter now.

*I make no claims that any of this is good coding practice

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eY3hM/